# Add tooltip via JavaScript in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do add a tooltip in Bootstrap v5 via Javascript?  I'm tying to add a tooltip and popover to the same element and it seems the best route is to enable both them via JS.

The tooltip added via html works as expected:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <span class="input-group-text mb-3" id="basic-addon2" title="If you want us">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                                <path d="M8.93 6.588l-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                            </svg>
    </span>
```

Next I tried to add the tooltip via JS:

```js
                var options =
                {
                    title : "If you want us",
                };
                
                var responseTeamMemberSpanElm = document.getElementById("basic-addon2");
                var tooltipResponseTeamMember = new bootstrap.Tooltip(responseTeamMemberSpanElm,options );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<span class="input-group-text mb-3" id="basic-addon2" >
                            <!-- info icon with circle around: from https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/info-circle/ -->
                            <svg "basic-addon2-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                                <path d="M8.93 6.588l-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                            </svg>
    </span>
```

The look of the tooltip looks different.  Also, I can put my cursor on the grey background, the tooltip works as expected but when I hover over the circle "i", the tooltip stops working.  After I hover over the circle "i", I see the tooltip get moved to the bottom of the screen and the tooltip doesn't work even if I hover elsewhere and come back to the background.

All the older answers I found are using the JQuery version of bootstrap.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you define **css propertry** `pointer-events: none;` in `all child` of `tooltip element` then its working fine but this may be create a problems on **click, hover, focus and other events listener**.

So `re-initialize` tooltip method when hide tooltip by `hide.bs.tooltip` method in Bootstrap-v5.

***Source:*** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#events

Try below snippet.

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    this.addEventListener('hide.bs.tooltip', function () {
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <span class="input-group-text border position-relative" id="basic-addon2" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="If you want us">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z" />
                    <path
                        d="M8.93 6.588l-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 my-3">
            <span class="input-group-text border position-relative" id="basic-addon3" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="If you want us">
                <input type="text" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="First Name">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-info-circle"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z" />
                    <path
                        d="M8.93 6.588l-2.29.287-.082.38.45.083c.294.07.352.176.288.469l-.738 3.468c-.194.897.105 1.319.808 1.319.545 0 1.178-.252 1.465-.598l.088-.416c-.2.176-.492.246-.686.246-.275 0-.375-.193-.304-.533L8.93 6.588zM9 4.5a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z" />
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not following your suggestion.  In your sample, you have hard coded title="If you want us" in span element.  This won't work in my situation.  The tooltip and popover functions interpret the title differently.  I don't understand how doing the re-initialize will allow me to add a tooltip in JS.  Also, since using the build in tooltip (i.e., defining with title attribute) does not match the results of when I'm try to init the tooltip in JS, it tells me I'm missing something on my init.  Can you explain what you are thinking with the solution you proposed?

Comment: So you want dynamic tooltip? That should be single tooltip or may be multiple?

Comment: My end goal is to make both the hover show the tool tip and a click to show the tool tip.  One of the people I had test the form thought it didn't work since clicking did nothing.